# Hyperref (href) not using alternative to "www"

Tags: hyperref

I'm trying to use the `hyperref` package in Latex to link a specific website using `href`. The problem is that using a URL such that

```
\href{https://link.springer.com}{book}
```

produces a clickable link that tries to jump through my local directories.
The error is in the word "`link`" whereas using "`www`" will ATTEMPT to take me to a page that is not valid (a positive result). Any idea how to get this link to behave properly?

Comment: This could be a viewer issue. In a short example I just tried, the link as posted worked in TeXworks' preview, Adobe Reader DC, SumatraPDF. What reader do you use?

Answer (score 4):

Package `hyperref` does *not* change the URL:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \href{https://link.springer.com/}{book}
\end{document}
```

The PDF file contains:

```pdf
3 0 obj
<<
/Type /Annot
/Border[0 0 1]/H/I/C[0 1 1]
/Rect [147.716 656.239 171.018 665.15]
/Subtype/Link/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(https://link.springer.com/)>>
>>
endobj
```

BTW, the slash at the end completes the URL.

As can be seen, the URL does not contain `www`. Thus, the error is somewhere else. Maybe the PDF viewer or the web browser.

Comment: What tool do you use to see those PDF file contents?

Comment: @MaxSnippe You can just use a text editor (e.g. VIM).